# Bundling not work for me -MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**RegisterBundles :**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/AllScripts").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery.x123.{version}.js",
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "~/Scripts/jqRect.js"));
```

**In the Shared Layout file :**

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AllScripts")
```

**In Global.asax we have :**

```
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

The scripts didn't combined, also didn't get minified.

*This is in release mode.*

Is there anything missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your web.config you need to set the attribute `debug="false"` in the `<compilation>`-tag.

This means that you can use this flag to allow javascript debugging locally before deploying (debugging minified and bundled javascript is obviously next to impossible).

NOTE: The "Release mode" flag only affects the way the C# (or VB.NET) compiler compiles your classes and is not related to the `debug` attribute of the `<compilation>`-tag. Also note that the `debug` attribute controls whether ASP.NET MVC caches the location of views on disk and thus has a great performance impact: you should always have `debug=false` in a production environment.

Comment: Right, That was in release mode(In Visual Studio running setting) but seems it doesn't take effect there, and you are right, +1

Comment: this is the correct answer, SO forced me to wait before setting it as the answer and I'm waiting, Though I think their order is correct everything seems misordered, Is there anything else which I should take care of?

Comment: I believe it will rise to the top once you mark it as correct.

Comment: Friend I meant the scripts are ordered exactly as I were rendering them separately but in the bundled manner they look misordered, some seems doesn't work. Should I consider anything else?

Comment: Sorry! They are always ordered as per the ordering you use when you define the bundle. Maybe the "{version}" wildcard is causing inclusion of files you meant to leave out? I've seen this happen when you have multiple similarly-named files.

Answer (score 1):

When you develop your project with `Debug` mode, it doesn't combined and minified. However,
you can force it to do that by setting

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: Not sure but the below answer worked. Maybe as you said that could be a kinda more forcing to do so but yet seems we didn't need it. thanks +1 agha abbas